# Jrun ColdFusion service intermittently fails to start

Tags: coldfusion, windows-server-2008, jrun

We occasionaly have a problem where we attempt to start the Jrun service and it fails with the following two errors:

error JRun Naming Service unable to start on port 2902
java.net.BindException: Port in use by another service or process: 2902

info No JDBC data sources have been configured for this server (see jrun-resources.xml)
error java.net.BindException: Port in use by another service or process: 8300

We then have to reboot the machine and Jrun comes up with no problem.  This is very intermittent - happens perhaps one out of every 10 times we restart Jrun services.

I saw another reference on StackOverflow that if Windows Services take longer than 30 seconds to restart Windows shuts down the startup proccess.  Perhaps that is the issue here?  The logs indeed indicate that these errors are thrown about 37+ seconds after the restart command is issued.

We are on a 64bit platform on WinServer 2008.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

We've been experiencing a similar problem on some of our servers.  Unfortunately, netstat never indicated any sort of actual port conflict for us.  My suspicion is that it's related to our recent deployment of a ColdFusion "cumulative hotfix" to our servers.  We use the multi-server edition of CF 8.0.1 enterprise with a large number of instances on each machine -- each with its own JVM and its own distinct set of ports.  Each CF instance is attached to its own IIS website and runs as its own Windows Service.

Within the past few weeks, we started getting similar "port in use" exceptions on startup, on our 32-bit machines as well as our 64-bit machines, all of which are running Windows Server 2003.  I found several possible culprits and tried the following:

1. In jrun-jms.xml for each CF instance, there's an entry for the RMI transport layer that reads `<port>0</port>` -- which, according to the JRun documentation, means "choose a random port."  I made that non-random and distinct per instance (in the 2600-2650 range) and restarted each instance.  Things improved temporarily, perhaps coincidentally.
2. In the same file, under the entry for the TCPIP transport later, every instance defaulted to `<port>2522</port>` -- so I changed those to distinct ports per instance in the 2500-2550 range and restarted each instance.  That didn't seem to help at all.
3. I tried researching whether ports in the 2500-3000 range might be used for any other purpose, and I couldn't find anything obvious, and besides, netstat wasn't telling me that any of my choices were in use.
4. I found something online about Windows designating ports from 1024 to 5000 as the "dynamic port" range, so I added 10000 to the port numbers I had set in jrun-jms.xml and restarted each instance again.  Still didn't help.
5. I tried changing the port in jndi.properties, also by adding 10000 to the port numbers.  Unfortunately this meant wiping out all my wsconfig connections to IIS and creating them again from scratch.  I had to edit wsconfig_jvm.config as well, adding `-DWSConfig.PortScanStartPort=12900` to java.args, so it could detect my CF instances.  (By default it only scans ports 2900-3000.  See [bpurcell.org](http://www.bpurcell.org/blog/index.cfm?mode=entry&entry=949) for details.  It's an old post but still relevant.)  So far so good!

My best guess is that Adobe (or MS Windows) changed the way some of its code grabs "random" ports.  But all I know for sure so far is that the steps outlined above appear to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you verified that the services are in fact stopping? Task manager should show no instances of jrun.exe. You can also check to see what is bound to that port by opening a command window and running

`netstat -a -b`

This will list all your open ports, plus what program is using them. You can also use

```
netstat -a -o
```

Which does the same thing as the above, but will list the process id instead of the program name. You can then cross-reference those with task manager. You'll need to enable showing the PIDs in task manager by going to View->Select Columns and making sure PID is checked. My guess would be that the jrun processes are not shutting down in a timely fashion.